# How to use BLENC in PHP?

Tags: php, encryption

I have a testcode.php file need to encode:

```
<?php
    $hello = "Hello World!";
?>
```

And I created file encode.php to encrypt and test that file:

```
<?php
    /* read the PHP source code */
    $source_code = file_get_contents("testcode.php");

    /* create the encrypted version */
    $redistributable_key = blenc_encrypt($source_code, "encrypt.php");

    /* read which is the key_file */
    $key_file = ini_get('blenc.key_file');

    /* save the redistributable key */
    file_put_contents($key_file, $redistributable_key, FILE_APPEND);

    include 'encrypt.php';
    echo $hello;
?>
```

but I recevied these errors when I ran encode.php:

> Warning: blenc_compile: Validation of script 'encrypt.php' failed.
>   MD5_FILE: 910e6a45f806ba3dc42830839971cb53
>   MD5_CALC: c38a6b2f389267a272ea656073a463ed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPEncode\encode.php on line 14

and

> Fatal error: blenc_compile: Validation of script 'encrypt.php' failed,
>   cannot execute. in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPEncode\encode.php on line 14

Help me fix it, thank you! :)

Comment: `encrypt.php` - is this file present in your application?

Comment: yes, it presented in my application.

Comment: One more attempt to obfuscate simple php code. Why do people go on doing that? What for?

Comment: @arkascha ^^! I need to encode a PHP Project to secure, this is an example and it's very simple :D

Comment: Sorry, but I doubt obfuscation does offer any real "security". Typically such attempts only appear to lock things. But even the documentation claims that this is not proof. IN the end all information required to run the script must be present on the executing system. That _cannot_ be "secure". That's why obfuscation is a false friend. In the end it makes things more insecure.

Comment: @KenPlus have you solved this issue?

Comment: @CJRamki No, I didn't. I have changed xampp's directory to other drive to avoid windows' permission but it still did not run.

Answer (score 2):

BLENC has issues when there is more than one redistributable key in blenc.key_file. See [PHP bug #68490](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68490) that I've reported.

Also when you run your script multiple times, redistributable keys will get corrupted in blenc.key_file. This is because you are appending to the file, but all keys are saved on the same line (the same broken example is on php manual page). You should change it to:

```
file_put_contents($key_file, $redistributable_key."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

The second Fatal error you got was probably because of corrupted blenc.key_file.

Answer (score 1):

;) just delete "`<?php ?>`" in your page *.php
compiled this not with "`<?php and ?>`"

just
    $hello = "Hello World!";

and is ok :) !

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full location of the `blenc.key_file` in `php.ini` variable called `blenc.key_file` or via `.htaccess` , setting at runtime with `ini_set()` is not possible (at this moment the key file has already been read).

`.htaccess` example:

```
php_value blenc.key_file /path/path/path/key_file.blenc
```

Every time you encrypt a file a new $redistributable_key will be generated! 
You have to include all keys in the key@
Or use a fixed (private) encryption key for all your encryption:

```
$private_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxVCHANGEME";
$redistributable_key = blenc_encrypt($source_code, "encrypt.php", $private_key);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $file_name = basename($file);

    $source_code = file_get_contents($file);

    //This covers old-asp tags, php short-tags, php echo tags, and normal php tags.
    $contents = preg_replace(array('/^<(\?|\%)\=?(php)?/', '/(\%|\?)>$/'), array('',''), $source_code);

    $html .= "<br> BLENC blowfish unencrypted key: $unencrypted_key" . PHP_EOL;
    $html .= "<br> BLENC file to encode: " . $file_name . PHP_EOL;

    //file_put_contents('blencode-log', "---\nFILE: $file_name\nSIZE: ".strlen($contents)."\nMD5: ".md5($contents)."\n", FILE_APPEND);

    $redistributable_key = blenc_encrypt($contents, TARGET_DIR . '/blenc/' . $file_name, $unencrypted_key);
    $html .= "<br> BLENC size of content: " . strlen($contents) . PHP_EOL;

    /**
    * Server key
    * key_file.blenc
    */
    file_put_contents(TARGET_DIR . '/blenc/' . 'key_file.blenc', $redistributable_key . PHP_EOL);
    $html .= "<br> BLENC redistributable key file key_file.blenc updated." . PHP_EOL;
    exec("cat key_file.blenc >> /usr/local/etc/blenckeys");
?>
```

https://github.com/codex-corp/ncryptd/blob/master/app/controllers/MagicalController.php#L479